# Мылится изображение после загрузки, на мобильном

Tags: html, css, responsive

Сразу после загрузки страницы на мобильном всё резкое, и шрифты и изображения, но через секунду всё слегка размыливается. В Чём может быть проблема? 
[image: Это сразу после загрузки]

[image: Это через секунды две]

Comment: без изображения не понятно

Comment: @Duoxx Добавил в описание скрины.

Comment: Анимации какие-нибудь есть при загрузке?

Comment: @l2banners нет, из анимаций на странице есть только animate {opacity} для меню, но оно активируется только при нажатии на кнопку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Нашёл ответ!**
Возможно у кого-то будет такая проблема, но сомневаюсь. 
Суть - у меня в подвале был логотип, и так как он был не png а jpg, а фон подвала был серый а не белы, я решил не заморачиватся с созданием png лого, а просто к этому сделать смешивание цветов через css (mix-blend-mode), вот в этом то дело и было, убрал смешивание цветов и сделал png лого, теперь всё хорошо!